# Replacing content of html document

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to replace a word in an html document with selected word using javascript.

**JavaScript**

```
var node=document.body;
var childs=node.childNodes;
var n=childs.length,i=0;

while (i < n) {
    node=childs[i];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        if (node.textContent) {
            node.nodeValue=node.nodeValue.replace("injected","hai");
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

but string is not getting replaced...pls help

Comment: please provide your mark up

Comment: Are none of the provided answers helpful? If so, please click accept on the best one.

Answer (score 3):

Add `document.body=node;` at the end. When you set node to equal body you are copying the value, not editing it by reference.

Comment: then it gets following error" Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're trying to work with the text node directly. `console.log` on `nodeValue` shows that the textContent of displayed tags is neither retrieved nor set in your code.

This works great. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/eBUlUva/2/edit)

```
<p>something to be replaced.</p>
```

and the js:

```
var childs = document.body.childNodes;

var len = childs.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
  var node=childs[i];
  if (node.nodeName === 'P') {
    node.textContent = node.textContent.replace("to be replaced","was replaced");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler method using the String `replace` method. For example, you can convert the body of the page into a string and use regular expressions to replace the word. This means that you can avoid having to traverse the entire DOM and node lists, which is unnecessarily slow for your task.

`document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML.replace("injected","hai")`